# loading two components in angular2 non SPA

Tags: angular

Given the following components.
I want to use these components on a non SPA web site exactly like the [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/A7fyFUST9IdP1FriauXk?p=preview). This sample is no longer valid, as the latest beta of angular 2 uses modules, bootstrap is no longer defined, and I cannot get the two components to work in parallel.

// Our first component.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'comp1',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h3>Hello, {{name}}</h3>

    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class Comp1 {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'I am ng2 component 1'
  }
}
```

// Our second component.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'comp2',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h3>Hello, {{name}}</h3>

    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class Comp2 {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'I am ng2 component 2'
  }
}
```

There is a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/A7fyFUST9IdP1FriauXk?p=preview), using a beta version of angular.
How do I register these two components using the latest version of angular 2. The sample is not longer valid for the newer angular versions.

When I attempt to import bootstrap, the newer versions of angular are structured differently.

```
import {platform} from '@angular/core';
// platform is undefined.
import { bootstrap, BROWSER_PROVIDERS, BROWSER_APP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/platform-browser';
// bootstrap is undefined, BROWSER_PROVIDERS is undefined etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to anyone else attempting this, is to create two modules, and [register each module separately](http://plnkr.co/edit/wDaUF4rEkpuceVkAREfk?p=preview)

Registration

```
//main entry point
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModuleA, AppModuleB} from './app';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModuleA);
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModuleB);
```

Modules

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppA ],
  bootstrap: [ AppA ]
})
export class AppModuleA {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppB ],
  bootstrap: [ AppB ]
})
export class AppModuleB {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing a module definition e.g.:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {Comp1} from './comp1';
import {Comp2} from './comp2';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        Comp1,
        Comp2
    ],
    bootstrap: [Comp1]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: what you say makes sense, but then I seem unable to use the two components as peers.
<one></one>
STATIC CONTENT<two></two>, as in the plunker. angular2 seems to only play nicely for SPA apps.

Comment: I am not quite sure of what you want to achieve, but as far as I understand you need to have a main component to bootstrap. It can be a simple wrap for the router to switch between your 2 components.

Comment: what I want to achieve is exactly the same as the plunker, only with the latest version of angular2, the plunker is from an older version. If I just update the angular versions to beta.17, I get the error. core_1.platform is not a function.

Comment: Ok, I see. Sorry for misunderstanding then.