# Angular2-dart in non SPA

Tags: angular-dart, angular2-dart

I would like to  use angular2-dart in non-spa as in

[loading two components in angular2 non SPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584859/loading-two-components-in-angular2-non-spa)

i.e.  in any non-spa page  (not just index.html), I would like to have something  like

```
<body>
  <my-app-a>
    loading...
  </my-app-a>

  Static content 

  <my-app-b>
      loading ..
  </my-app-b>
 </body>
```

How can this be done using angular2-dart? This will allow to   bootstrap arbitrary Angular2-dart component(s)  in  any  non-spa page.

Comment: I am not sure this is possible,
Did you try to call the bootstrap method 2 times ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `bootstrap()` twice in `web/main.dart`, like this:

```
void main() {
  bootstrap(AppComponent);
  bootstrap(App2Component);
}
```

I just tried it and it works fine.